# Put Method In Express Giving Empty Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**SO when I am creating a simple REST API and I am using res.route and in it I am doing a get request and a put request but when i trigger  put request it does not do anything and POSTMAN just give a empty string i am using mongodb as database and mongoose `enter code here`  **

```js
app.route("/articles/:ReqTitle")
  .get(function(req, res){
    const RequestedArtical = req.params.ReqTitle;
    Article.findOne({title: RequestedArtical}, function(err, FoundArticle){
      if(FoundArticle){
        res.send(FoundArticle);
      }else{
        res.send("No artice with that title was found");
      }
    });
  }
).put(function(req, res){
    const RequestedArtical = req.params.ReqTitle;
    Article.updateOne({title: RequestedArtical},
      {title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content},                              
      {overwrite: true},
      function(err){
        if(!err){
          res.send("Sucessfulyy updated the article");                                           
        }else{
          res.send(err);
        }
      }
    );
  }  
);
```

Comment: It would help if you used punctuation in your English sentences. Why make it harder for people to understand your question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will try to improve it as English is not my first language and kindly can you look at question and try to help me it will mean a lot

Comment: Please count the commas and full-stops in your question and then again in your comment. I honestly don't think you are trying. At least the concept of full-stops should exist in virtually all languages. In Pakistan, e.g., both English and Urdu, have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `{overwrite: true},` and The MongoDB server disallows overwriting documents using `updateOne` [FYI](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#update). So, from the Documentation, if  you use `overwrite: true`, you should use `replaceOne()`

```
put(function(req, res) {
            const RequestedArtical = req.params.ReqTitle;
            console.log(RequestedArtical);
            Article.replaceOne({
                    title: RequestedArtical
                }, {
                    title: req.body.title,
                    content: req.body.content
                },
                //{overwrite: true},
                                
                function(err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        res.send("Sucessfulyy updated the article");
                    } else {
                        res.send(err);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

Same as `update()`, except `MongoDB` replace the existing document with the given document `(no atomic operators like $set)`.